# Django url template confusion

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Okay I am having a bit of an issue.

I want to create a button with a link, and right now I am using `action={% url views.contest_overview %}` in hopes that the reverse lookup by Django will match     `(r'^category/$', views.contest_overview),` in my urls.py. However, this is not working and I can't figure out the proper nomenclature, despite numerous guesses.

The error I get (with my best guess above) is:

> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for
>   'views.contest_overview' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{}' not found.

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Use the application name in the `url` tag, e.g. `{% url myapp.views.contest_overview %}`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do; I give names to my url. For example:

url(r'^account/register/$', 'someapp.views.register_view', **name='account_register'**),

Therefore in template, I can do this:

```
{% url account_register as url_acc_register %}
<html>
..
..
<a href="{{ url_acc_register }}">Some link </a>
```